# PHP app - how and where is the best way to safe settings

Tags: php, configuration, settings, storage

I am developping a PHP app with admin panel. In that admin panel the admin can, for example choose how many articles to be on page ect. ect. My question is where to save this settings. I don't think that DB is good answer, because a whole table with only one row sounds dumb. I think that xml file is the best way to do that, but are there any other ways?

Comment: Nothing wrong with a one-row table with one setting per field. The alternative is a two column setting/value pair with multiple records. Both have points for/against. Repeated loading/parsing of XML will probably end up being more expensive than a simple one-row DB query.

Comment: Sounds like you are new to databases. Don't let them scare you - they are just glorified text files built for this type of thing.

Comment: @Marc: Speaking out of experience: It is more expensive.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, I really think you should reevaluate a database solution. Could be something like:

```
key          | value
-------------------------
some setting | it's value
```

Having worked a lot with XML files in PHP, I must warn you that in the end I almost always wish I'd gone with a database approach from the beginning. It's faster and much easier, especially if you require manipulation from the app.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I would also add that APC or Memcache should be added in between - to cache config settings until they are changed so you don't have to bother the database every page load.

Answer (score 0):

1. PHP file produced using `var_export()`
2. ini file produced using some ini-files handling library.
3. Nothing wrong with database though.

Comment: I think I'll go with the ini file. Thanks a lot dude.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use either an `.ini` or `.csv` file if you don't want to go down the database or XML route.

PHP has good support for CSV files so that could be a good option.